# Restart activity as e.g. orientation change does

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I want my app to support different layouts for right-handed and left-handed users. So after changing the respective preference I want to restart the activity in the same way as it restarts when e.g. orientation changes.

What I tried so far:

**1.**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

This does not store and load the saved instance state

**2.**

```
View cv = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

SparseArray<Parcelable> state = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
cv.saveHierarchyState(state);
setContentView(desiredCv);

cv = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
cv.restoreHierarchyState(state);
```

Even then many things aren't as they should be.

I think that in the end I could figure out how to change layout properly without restarting but it would be much easier to do it in the same way as for system-defined configuration changes.

Comment: Why dont you use fragments and switch them based on user selection?

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, you should manually save the instance state and pack it into the intent you're sending to the new activity. Fragments would be cleaner, though.

Comment: @PravinCG I will give fragments a try but I hoped that there would be a simpler solution because the app would actually not need the additional functionality and complexity of fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Fragments` and do it programmatically. Following the same way you could also rearrange dinamically your elements in the UI but I think it would be complicated to maintain.

`OnSaveInstanceState()` is not called on an Activity being finish-ed. And I'm not aware of a way to let Android handle this for you.

The solution may be to create 2 different layout files. Then you programmatically select the right one in the `onCreate()` method based on the preference value that has been updated.

If your two layouts use the same ids for those views that you need to restore, then you can implement two methods that save these states in a `Bundle` and retrieve these states from the `Bundle`. When you want to change layout, start a new activity with the proper intent (telling the activity which layout to load); in the bundle associated with this intent save what you need and retrieve it in `onCreate()` to update the views. You don't need to duplicate the code in the case you use layout dx or sx; you can use the same code since the two layouts use the same ids.

In this way you still have your one activity and can reuse your code. And the same code you use to restore the state between layout changes can still be used with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`, since, again, the ids are the same.

To make it short, use bundles.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using API level 11 or higher (Android 3.0 or later), you can call `recreate()` in your activity. This will destroy the current instance and create a new one and should do the same thing as what happens during a configuration change (ie `onSaveInstanceState()` will be called, etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately I need it also for lower versions (at least Android 2.2)